# Long distance light detection in daylight

Tags: photodiode, ldr, remote-sense

I am attempting to develop a system that is linked with streetlight lamps. There are challenges that I can think of:

1. Light sensing in daylight (or climate changing) situations.
2. Long distance (20-30m) between the sensor and the target (lamp.)

Probably there are different solutions. Considering the given distance, I think:

1. The sensor needs a lens to detect objects at a distance.
2. Alternatively, I could use live-streamed video input and process the image.
3. If the power cable for the lamp is more approachable, I may be able to detect the magnetic field.

I am wondering if there are already any of these purpose sensor modules available for this purpose. Could you suggest any more simple, elegant way to do this?

Comment: *Alternatively, I could use live-streamed video input and process the image.* Um, how is that going to work without a lens?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Detect a broken street light?

Comment: Do you specifically need to be tied to a particular street light, or can you just sense nightfall?

Comment: @Marcus Müller In case the area cannot be zoomed enough on Zoom, it may be possible to crop and detect video input from a regular webcam using OpenCV.

Comment: @LordTeddy I want to be able to detect the particular streetlight that is located approximately 30 meters away.

Comment: @Lior Bilia I want to detect the specific moment when the particular streetlight turns on and off.

Comment: @MiniJ what I was hinting at that your camera will need a pretty nice lens

Answer (score 1):

Image the light onto a photodiode and then bandpass the 100/120 Hz flicker from the lights. This will reject sunlight and give you a measure of how much artificial light is present.

You would have a problem if a street light was totally flickerless, but you should be able to detect extremely low levels of flicker with a narrow enough filter so I doubt you'll find such a light. Could even lock into the line frequency if needed to have extremely high sensitivity.

Comment: "*... the 100/120 Hz flicker from the lights.*" Hmmm, that would have been good 20 years ago, but with LED street lights driven from an SMPS?

Comment: @Transistor You could lock onto the switching frequency in that case, but I actually think even LED lighting you would still be able to see the mains flicker too on a lot of lights. Both because the power supply doesn't have to be switching and because it is tolerable in lighting circuits to allow some drop out and so save on capacitors.

Comment: @user1850479 Thank you. That's a great tip though I still have to solve the sensing range(distance) problem.

Comment: @MiniJ Use a lens to image the light onto a photodiode. Streetlights are very bright so you have a lot of light to work with as long as you pick a vantage point where you can see the light directly.